# Lines of Level Curves of an Analytic Function's Real and Imaninary Parts

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the following question:

Let $g(z)$ be analytic at $z_{0}$ and let $g'(z_{0})=0$ and $g''(z_{0})\neq 0$ so that near $z_{0}$,$g(z)-g(z_{0})=[w(z)^{2}]$ for $w$ analytic, $w'(z_{0})\neq 0$.

Prove that there are exactly two perpendicular curves on which $Re(g)$ (alternatively, $Im(g)$) are constant through $z_{0}$. Show also that lines of constant $Re(g)$ and $Im(g)$ intersect at $45 ^{\circ}$.

I know that if a function $f$ analytic on a domain and $f(z_{0})\neq 0$ then $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ are harmonic conjugate and their level curves passing through $z_{0}$ intersect at right angles at $z_{0}$. But how we interprete the fact that $g'(z_{0})=0$ to get the conclusion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $w$ is such that $w(z_0)=0$ and $w'(z_0)\neq 0$. Therefore we suppose $z_0=g(z_0)=0$ and write
$$w(z)=az+z^2\beta(z)$$
with $\beta$ a holomorphic function, $a\in\mathbb{C}$. There exists a neighbourhood $U=\{|z|<\epsilon\}$ such that $w'(z)\neq 0$ for $z\in U$, so $w$ is a conformal mapping from $U$ onto $w(U)=W\subseteq\mathbb{C}_\zeta$ (complex plane with $\zeta$ coordinate).
The set $\{z\in U\ :\ \mathrm{Re}\;w^2(z)=0\}$ is mapped by $w$ onto the set
$$\{\zeta\in W\ :\ \mathrm{Re}\;\zeta^2=0\}$$
which is union of two perpendicular lines through the origin (the two bisectors).
In the same way, the set $\{z\in U\ :\ \mathrm{Im}\;w^2(z)=0\}$ is mapped by $w$ onto the set
$$\{\zeta\in W\ :\ \mathrm{Im}\;\zeta^2=0\}$$
which is union of two perpendicular lines through the origin (the two axes).

Moreover, these two pairs of lines are mutually inclined by $45^\circ$.

Now, as we said, $w$ (and hence also its inverse) is a conformal mapping from $U$ to $W$ (both neighbourhoods of the origin), so it preserves angles between curves.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain why the set is the union of two perpendicular lines through the origine? If I write $w(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ then I have $u(z)=v(z)$ or $u(z)=-v(z)$ by $Re (w^{2}(z))=0$ then the inner product of gradu and gradv is 0 since u and v are the harmonic conjugates. Is this the reason?

Comment: What I am saying is that a neighbourhood of $z_0$ in the set you want to study is conformally mapped onto a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $x^2-y^2=0$ ... the set which is union of two perpendicular lines is $\{\zeta\in W\ :\ \mathrm{Re}\;\zeta^2=0\}$ which, if $\zeta=x+iy$, is given by the equation $x^2=y^2$ ...

Comment: And similarly for the imaginary part, only with $\mathrm{Im}\zeta^2=0$ which is $xy=0$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.